# Public key authentication on Windows OpenSSH server

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, openssh, private-key

I have two Windows machines running on Ubuntu virtual box. Both machines have OpenSSH installed. I can connect from one to another using `ssh` and passwords, but I can not figure out how to use keys.

I generated keys on the client machine using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, saved the public key on the remote machine as `authorized_keys` in the folder `C:\Users\username\.ssh` and changed the settings to `PasswordAuthentication no` in `Program Files\OpenSSH\etc\sshd_config` and restarted SSH server. When I try to connect I get an error

> Permission denied (public key,keyboard-interactive)

Comment: What's your OpenSSH Windows installation based on? Cygwin on MinGW? Why do you think that the `~` maps to `C:\Users\username`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to check if it is based on Cygwin, but `bin` directory contains `cygwin1.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Under Cygwin the root (`/`) maps by default to  `C:\cygwin` (or `cygwin64` on 64-bit).

So the `/home/username/.ssh` folder should be under `C:\cygwin\home\username\.ssh`